# В чем отличие MVP от MVVM

Tags: java, android, mvvm, шаблоны-проектирования, mvp

Не могу понять отличие реализации этих паттернов, кроме того, что в MVP вместе Presentera выступает ModelView , и подкручивается DataBinding.

Но тогда вопрос,в чем отличие паттернов ,  кроме использования DataBinding?

Comment: отличие паттернов в использовании биндинга. Если вам этого кажется мало, то стоит осмыслить, что это принципиально иной способ отображения данных на представлении, откуда идет принципиально иная логика всего взаимодействия компонентов.

Comment: Presenter и ViewModel это классы которые абсолютно отличаются по своему поведению и для воторого необходимо иметь DataBinding. Основное отличие что при MVVM вы можете в один View иметь бинд data которая будет предоставляться от разных VM.  В MVP -> 1 Presenter к 1 View. Но абсолютно согласен комментом выше, если сделать даже небольшой проект в 2-х этих паттернах, они будут очень сильно отличаться, такой рефакторинг очень тяжел.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Наличие автоматического связывания (databinding) является главным отличием MVVM паттерна от паттерна MVP (в MVP Presenter изменяет View путём вызова на ней методов через предоставленный интерфейс).